# How to pass function as variable in Express-handlebars

Tags: node.js, function, express, mongoose, express-handlebars

I am trying to pass a function as a variable and call that function using onclick="" 
but the function is executing before passing.

Here is the code.

seminar.js

```
function getco(){
  console.log('hello');
}
router.get('/add',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('cms/seminar/add',{
    getco:getco()
  });
});
```

add.handlebars

```
<form action="/cms/seminar/add" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
          <label for="sel1">Game Name of the Seminar</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="seminar_gamename" name="seminar_gamename" required onclick="getco">
              <option value="pubg">Pubg</option>
              <option value="candy_crush">Candy Crush</option>
              <option value="fortnite">Fortnite</option>
              <option value="mortal_combat">Mortal Combat 11</option>
              <option value="far_cry_city">Far Cry City Dowm</option>
              <option value="fortnite">Fortnite</option>
              <option value="prince_of_persia">Prince of Persia:The Forgotten Sand</option>
            </select>
        </div>
</form>
```

//But the result im getting is 'hello' without even clicking

Comment: `getco:getco()` this line is executing during `render` if you want to pass you should not invoke it `getco:getco`. This would send the source of the function as `string`. So it makes me ask, what are you trying to achieve doing that?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment above you are directly calling the function instead of passing it to frontend.

Try removing *()* from *getco*

```
`function getco(){
  console.log('hello');
}
router.get('/add',(req,res)=>{
  res.render('cms/seminar/add',{
    getco:getco
  });
});`
```

This allows you to pass the method as a variable and then in frontend use,

`onclick="getco()"`

Comment: I tried to do so, but it is still not working.
I also tried onclick="{{getco}}" /* because using handlebars*/
onclick="getco"
and onclick="getco()"

in js file, i did like this 
getco:getco